# Predicting the resting offset in a UIScrollView after deceleration

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I would like to be able to predict the final resting offset within a UIScrollView after a flick gesture. It doesn't need to be pixel-accurate, but close enough so that the user does not perceive a difference (i.e. it doesn't move excessively less or more than they are used to).

I know someone will ask, so: Why? I have a table view-like menu control inside a UIScrollView. I would like to make it such that the top-most menu item is fully displayed and flush to the top of the UIScrollView. UIScrollView's paging feature is not quite what I want, because a strong flick doesn't fly past multiples of the view bounds.

Handling normal touch events is easy enough. On `touchesEnded:withEvent:`, I can scroll to the nearest full menu item. The hard part is deceleration.

There are two constants for the deceleration rate, `UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal` and `UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast`. Their values are 0.998 and 0.990 in iPhone OS 3.0. I have tried to figure out the math that Apple uses to slow movement, but I'm coming up empty.

If I can predict with some accuracy the final resting offset, then early during deceleration I can simply use `scrollRectToVisible:animated:` to move to an offset with a menu item flush to the top of the view bounds.

Do any math-inclined people know what Apple may be doing during deceleration? Should I collect a bunch of numbers of deceleration events, graph them and come up with something close?

Comment: Why can't you use a UITableView for this?

Comment: Oh, I see -- you want to snap to the nearest menu item when the scrolling finishes?

Comment: I will note that snapping to a menu item like this isn't a standard iOS behavior--  breaking the behavior a user expects (even in a subtle way, like this) can be jarring.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Control UIScrollView's targetContentOffset in iOS 5

iOS5 [`UIScrollViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html) has a new method: [`scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006923-CH3-SW15).

This fits perfectly with what you want to do.

> This method is not called when the value of the scroll view’s
>   pagingEnabled property is YES. Your application can change the value
>   of the targetContentOffset parameter to adjust where the scrollview
>   finishes its scrolling animation.

### Alternative Solution for iOS4 and Lower

Change the [`UIScrollView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)'s [`decelerationRate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW44) to [`UIScrollViewDecelerationFast`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast) and then in [`scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006923-CH3-SW5) move to the closest "page".

The fast deceleration makes the complete stopping / sliding over a little more natural / less obnoxious.

Comment: BTW it's 2016 now and the method `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:` **IS** called even when `pagingEnabled` is set to YES/true. It's useful for determining which page the user will land on right after they lift their finger, but before the rubber-banding animation finishes.

Answer (score 4):

You could watch the speed of scrolling while the UIScrollView is decelerating, and when the speed falls beneath a certain value, snap to the nearest menu item.

You will likely want to implement the [`UIScrollViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIScrollViewDelegate) methods [`scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidEndDragging%3awillDecelerate%3a) and [`scrollViewDidScroll:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll%3a). When the user lifts their finger to finish a scroll gesture, `scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:` will be called. Begin monitoring the `scrollViewDidScroll:` events, and watch the delta between the `UIScrollView`'s current position and its previous position, divided by the time delta:

```
float velocity = (currentPosition - lastPosition) / (currentTime - lastTime);
```

When the velocity falls below a minimum value, call `scrollRectToVisible:animated:` on the `UIScrollView`.

Comment: This is roughly what I ended up doing, but I'm still interested in suggestions for predicting this much earlier.

Comment: Would you be likely to get a noticeably better result by predicting it earlier?

Comment: Sure. The earlier I know where the animation ends, the smoother the animation will be. Consider: if the velocity threshold is 0, I must speed up (or reverse) the scroll movement to snap. As the threshold increases, that effect is less and less noticeable.

Comment: If you make the threshold large enough, is it still accurate enough? If not, try estimating it with a quadratic, rather than a linear approximation. (i.e. measure and predict acceleration as well as velocity)

Comment: @nornagon and Steve Madsen could you please help me on a similar issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731569/uitableview-inside-a-uiscrollview-scrolling-issue

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment (I guess I need 50 rep), so this is not a full answer, but given the 0.998 and 0.990 values for deceleration, my instincts are that they simply multiply the current velocity by the deceleration rate each frame.