# How to track uiscrollview offset faster than in scrollviewdid scroll?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I need to get `contentOffset` values for a `UIScrollView` (`UICollectionView` to be more exact) that are sampled at a very high frequency in order to transform a layer based on the `contentOffset` of that scrollview. I find that the sampling rate for in `scrollViewDidScroll` isn't fast enough to pickup `contentOffset` differences small enough perform smooth transformations when I swipe quickly. Is there a way to look for smaller differences or am I approaching this problem entirely wrong?

Comment: There isn't anything faster than that. That delegate method gets called *every* time the content offset of the scroll view changes, so there wouldn't be a point in sampling it any faster than that.

Comment: I see, I wonder how other people tie view transformations to scrolling. Is it possible that looking directly at the gesture recognizer might lead to better results?

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13404171/1835155

Comment: Your best bet is to use the `scrollViewDidScroll` method and create a way to smooth your animation between each call. Think of anti-aliasing where the processor fills in the gaps between pixels to give the effect that the image is smoother than it is.

Comment: Do it like an interactive custom transition animation: set the layer's `speed` to 0, attach an animation, and keep setting the layer's `timeOffset`, as I describe here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22677298/341994

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestions. I will try them out and see what works best.

Comment: you can have look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39482753/scrollviewdidscroll-does-not-catch-movement-continuously)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [scrollview Delegate methods](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview).

scrollViewWillBeginDragging() can solve you purpose.

The necessary documentation can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619394-scrollviewwillbegindragging)