# uitableview inside a uiscrollview (scrolling issue)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview, user-experience

I have got a uitableview inside of a uiscrollview.
So the uitableview is smaller than the uiscrollview. And when I start to scroll down on the uitableview and it reaches the bottom, I am able to scroll in the uiscrollview.
And it works fairly. But not perfectly.

I would like to make the ux perfect so the scrollview would be kind of an extension (or another section of the uitableview). I don't want to add any section or footerview at the bottom of the tableview.

I was wondering on doing this by implementing something like this:

//
if tableview didscroll to bottom

then scrollview scrolltorect xxx 
//

but it would only work if the uitableview was scrolling down.

I am not sure if this would replicate the correct ux behaviour.

Could you guys give me your advice on how to do this?

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: And what is the reason you do not want section or footer view at the bottom of the table view?

Comment: I have got some ui animations and actions that I would like to keep outside the uitableview.

Answer (score 0):

I found this very hard and difficult to execute so I changed my UI in order to put the bottom of the interface inside the tableview footer's view. This way the experience of scrolling my app got much smoother.